# jQuery get index of an item on click

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="owl-stage">
   <div class="owl-item active">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="slider-image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="slider-image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="slider-image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item">
    <div class="item">
        <video src="dummy" controls=""></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<a href="">Play Video</a>
```

When I click on play video button I want the index of the "owl-item" with video tag, it should be 3 in this case ! how ?

Comment: clarify your question more.

Comment: @Amit how is it not clear when you read the last line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this line `$(".owl-stage .owl-item video").closest(".owl-item").index();` it will return the index of `owl-item` in your case `3`

**Demo**

```js
$("a").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault()
  var index = $(".owl-stage .owl-item video").closest(".owl-item").index();
  console.log(index)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-stage">
  <div class="owl-item active">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="slider-image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="slider-image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="slider-image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item">
    <div class="item">
      <video src="dummy" controls=""></video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="">Play Video</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the jQuery `.index()` function

For more information see https://api.jquery.com/index/

Example code for your case:

```
   $(".owl-item").click(function(){
      var index = $(".owl-item").index(this);

       alert("Index:  "+index);
   });
```

Just a reminder, indexes are zero-based. So the first one will be 0.

**UPDATE**

I see you want to click on the link and not on `.owl-item`.

In that case use the following code:

```
$("a").click(function(){
      var index = $(".owl-item video").closest(".owl-item").index();

      alert("Index:  "+index);
});
```

Comment: The OP wants to get the index of owl-item on `<a href="">Play Video</a>` click

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/emrsn3s3/1/

```js
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($('video').closest('div.owl-item').index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-stage">
   <div class="owl-item active">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="slider-image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="slider-image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="slider-image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item">
    <div class="item">
        <video src="dummy" controls=""></video>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="">Play Video</a>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The OP says `When i click on play video button` aka the <a>